# Ordering alphanumeric data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have alphanumeric data as below:

```
L1
L2
L3A
L3B
L4
L6C
L8
L9
L10
L11
R1D
R2A
R2B
R2Z
R11
```

And I need the data in the below order:

```
L1
L2
L3B
L3A
L4
L6C
L8
L9
L10
L11
R1D
R2B
R2A
R2Z
R11
```

Please help to get the data in the above order.

Comment: Presented ordering is not consistent: there is seemingly no rule which says why `B` should come before `A`, but `Z` should come after `A`. If your requirement is really *that* strange, just define a table with ordering which would map letter to index.

Comment: To explain a little, first part looks like it uses lexicographical ordering (as `L` comes before `R`), then it uses natural ordering for numbers, and then it could have used reverse lexicographical ordering for second alphabetical ordering part, except that it clearly does not, as I said in previous comment.

Comment: The difficulty you have trying to solve what should be a trivial problem illustrates the importance of proper data modeling. In the same "single value" like `L3B` you combined together three different bits of information: `L` vs. `R`, then a number (which seems to have meaning, since you want to order by it), and then a further qualifier `A, B,...` (which may also be missing, or `null` if in a column by itself). Your data model violates First Normal Form, the most basic rule of proper table design. No wonder writing such a trivial query has become difficult!

Comment: If it is your decision to make, or if you can influence others to make it - change the table design immediately, to include three columns instead of this single one. One column for L or R (with a constraint that the values are not null and must be either L or R), one for the number (constrained to NOT NULL), and a third - which may be nullable - for the additional qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather strange ordering.  It is basically:

- Order by the first character
- Order by the length of the string, ignoring the last alphabetic character.
- Order by the value

You can implement this as:

```
order by substr(col, 1, 1),
         length(col) - (case when substr(col, -1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 1 else 0 end),
         col
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the quick response. Would it be possible to bring L3B before L3A?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test as
  2  (select 'L1'  col from dual union
  3   select 'L2'  col from dual union
  4   select 'L3A' col from dual union
  5   select 'L3B' col from dual union
  6   select 'L4'  col from dual union
  7   select 'L6C' col from dual union
  8   select 'L8'  col from dual union
  9   select 'L9'  col from dual union
 10   select 'L10' col from dual union
 11   select 'L11' col from dual union
 12   select 'R1D' col from dual union
 13   select 'R2A' col from dual union
 14   select 'R2B' col from dual union
 15   select 'R2Z' col from dual union
 16   select 'R11' col from dual)
 17  select col from test
 18  order by
 19    substr(col, 1, 1),
 20    to_number(regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1)),
 21    regexp_substr(col, '\w', 1, 3) desc;

COL
---
L1
L2
L3B
L3A
L4
L6C
L8
L9
L10
L11
R1D
R2Z
R2B
R2A
R11

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Many thanks Littlefoot. The query is working as expected :-)